# border-radius not working in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

My border radius settings are not working in `dompdf`. Here is my code:

```
$html ='
<style>
#test {
    background-color:blue;width:450px;height:800px;z-index:50;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 750px 150px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 750px 310px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 500px 120px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 450px 165px;
}
</style>
<div id="test">

</div>
';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
```

Comment: ok sir, but i have to use the proper open and close tags into my coding but border-radius is not supporting, it display like square div

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using? Also, what are you trying to achieve? I'm seeing a radius with your sample code (though it's probably not the desired result).

Comment: Also, see this issue: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/374

Comment: dompdf 0.6.1 beta version

Answer (score 2):

I looked up the [`border-radius` sample](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php#css_border_radius.html,html) and have some remarks:

- it seems like they're using the normal style names, not Mozilla specific ones.
- maybe only `border-radius` is supported and not the `border-xxxx-yyyy-radius`
- the radius values you're using are very large, start with smaller values.

Following the example, this should work:

```
$html ='
<style>
#test {
    background-color:blue;width:450px;height:800px;z-index:50;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 100px 100px;
}
</style>
<div id="test">

</div>
';
```

Comment: this is not working, now it display same as the previous style

Comment: do you see the `div` at all?

Comment: yes, i have 1 doubt, if they use any external links for support the css3 techniques

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same issue in the current DOMPDF version 0.8 supports the border-radius feature.

I've also used the version 0.6 and there it doesn't work.

Comment: I use version 0.8.6. The border-radius not works on table and td tags.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below css helped me, Hope that will work for you.

> display: inline-block;